# Intel Core i7-3612QM multi-core CPU not being utilised properly

Tags: 14.04, dell, intel, cpu, multi-core

I have a Dell Inspiron 7520 with an Intel Core i7-3612QM CPU that repeatedly cycles through 100% usage of each individual core while barely using any other core as shown in the screen shot below.

[image: CPU Usage Snapshot]

This happens regardless of what I'm running and might be what's causing my laptop to heat up, how would I go about making my laptop use all of the cores concurrently?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: It will help if you tell us what version of the OS you are using (report uname -a) and what application you are running.

Comment: I'd also recommend running the stress utility  `sudo apt-get install stress` then the command `stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 20s` while running your system monitor.

Comment: I copied that set of instructions and all my CPU's even out at 90-100% before going back to 1 of them being at 100%, could you give me more info on what is that command does?

Comment: The command creates several threads, each of which is assigned a task (endlessly running square roots, for example is the CPU task)  `man stress` will give you lots of information about the program.  It appears then that your OS and computer run correctly (stress causes all the processors to top out) but you ave *a program* which is not operating on all processors.  Use of the program `top` will tell you what program is eating all of the CPU time on the single processor.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to spread a single threaded processes over multiple cores evenly. A single threaded process can only run on one core at a given time and the kernel might move the process/thread to another core while the programm runs. 
If one process is running at 100% on one core all the time you should check for that process and why it is utilizing one core.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how would I go about checking exactly what process is using a specific core? I've got this recurrently though which is why I feel it's a system and not a process-specific issue if that makes sense

Comment: To check which process is running at 100%, I would recommend `htop` or `top`. Depending on that, maybe something is running that does not need to run or could also indicate a misconfiguration. For top you also could use `top -n1` for a one shot output.